# How to play a audio file on HTML page from a zipfile which contains .wav file in memory?

Tags: python, flask, audio

I am building a webapp where I will get a zipfile from API call. This Zipfile contains an audio file which I have to play on the browser. I can't store the audio files on server and read them back.

This is my flask webpage, which renders download.html webpage.

```py
zipped_file = io.BytesIO(out_bytes) 
with ZipFile(zipped_file, 'r') as zf:
        zf.printdir()
        filename = zf.infolist()[0].filename
        buff = zf.read(filename) 

 return render_template('download.html', value = buff)
```

In download.html I have to play the audio from file we unzipped.

```html
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
   <source src="{{value}}">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

I am new to flask, if you have any ideas on how to play an audio without storing it in server please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to base64 encode your `buff` bytes, then prefix your `src` attribute with `data:audio/wav;base64,`:

```
import base64
zipped_file = io.BytesIO(out_bytes) 
with ZipFile(zipped_file, 'r') as zf:
    zf.printdir()
    filename = zf.infolist()[0].filename
    buff = zf.read(filename)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(buff)

return render_template('download.html', value = encoded)
```

```
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="data:audio/wav;base64,{{value}}">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks Afro its working after a small change. after encoding the data has b' character at the beginning due to which audio was not playing. I decoded the encoded data using `.decode('utf8')` and the b' character was gone.